# How to Create ListView From SQLite Database using cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have created a database which contains ID, Name, Family, Age, Student ID, Student Phone Number. Now, I'm trying to retrieve the Name and Family of students by searching the ID and then display the retrieved data in a custom list view using cursor adapter, but my code doesn't work.
Please tell me how to display retrieved data in a list view

here I post my code:

**DatabaseManager.java**

```
package com.example.tempcursoradapter;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public DatabaseManager(Context context)
    {
        super(context,"myDB",null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String query= "CREATE TABLE tbl_student ( "+
                " ID            INT            PRIMARY KEY"+
                " UNIQUE,"+
                " Name          VARCHAR( 50 ),"+
                " Family        VARCHAR( 50 ),"+
                " Age           INT,"+
                " StudentNumber VARCHAR( 11 ),"+
                " Tel           VARCHAR( 15 )"+ 
                " );";
        db.execSQL(query);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_student");
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public boolean addStudent (Student student)
    {
        boolean result;
        try{
        String query="INSERT INTO tbl_Student (ID,Name,Family,Age,StudentNumber,Tel) " +
                "VALUES ("+student.ID+",'"+student.Name+"','"+student.Family+"',"+27+",'"
                +student.stdNum+"','"+student.Tel+"')";
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
        result = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        result=false;
        }

        return result;
        }


    public boolean updataStudent (Student student)
    {
        boolean result;
        try{
        String query ="UPDATE tbl_Student  SET Name='"+student.Name+"',Family='"+student.Family+
                "',Age="+student.age+",StudentNumber='"+student.stdNum+"',Tel='"+student.Tel+"'" +
                " where ID = "+student.ID+"";
        SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
        result =true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            result= false;
        }
        return result;
        }

    public Cursor getStudent (int id)
    {

        String query ="SELECT Name,Family FROM tbl_Student";
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(query, null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public int getStudentCount()
    {
        int result=0;
        String query="SELECT * FROM tbl_student";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);
        result=cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }

    public boolean deleteStudent (int id)
    {
        boolean result;
        try{
        String query ="DELETE FROM tbl_student WHERE ID="+id;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
        result=true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            result=false;
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

**Student.java**

```
package com.example.tempcursoradapter;

public class Student {
    public int ID,age;
    public String Name,Family,stdNum,Tel;


}
```

**TodoCursorAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.tempcursoradapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TodoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
      public TodoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
          super(context, cursor, 0);
      }


      @Override
      public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
          return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false);
      }


      @Override
      public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
          // Find fields to populate in inflated template
          TextView tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
          TextView tvFamily = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvfamily);
          // Extract properties from cursor
          String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
          String priority = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Family"));
          // Populate fields with extracted properties
          tvName.setText(body);
          tvFamily.setText(String.valueOf(priority));
      }


    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.tempcursoradapter;



import android.R.integer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // add 10 sample data to database
        final DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(this);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
             Student student = new Student();
            student.ID=j;
            student.Name="name_"+String.valueOf(j);
            student.Family="family_"+String.valueOf(j);
            student.age=j;
            student.stdNum="stdNum_"+String.valueOf(j);
            student.Tel="telNum_"+String.valueOf(j);
             db.addStudent(student);
        }
// search for ID=1 
// I didn't used a Edit Text for input for simplicity and I only search for ID=1 
     Cursor todoCursor = db.getStudent(1);
// I know this line is my code's problem. my code crash at this line!
     TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, todoCursor,0);

     lv.setAdapter(todoAdapter);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**This is outputy LogCat**

```
02-27 12:28:54.129: E/Trace(6837): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-27 12:28:55.258: D/dalvikvm(6837): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 44K, 7% free 2555K/2720K, paused 44ms, total 50ms
02-27 12:28:55.268: I/dalvikvm-heap(6837): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.216MB for 635812-byte allocation
02-27 12:28:55.328: D/dalvikvm(6837): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3173K/3344K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
02-27 12:28:55.458: D/dalvikvm(6837): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3190K/3344K, paused 7ms+19ms, total 130ms
02-27 12:28:55.958: D/AndroidRuntime(6837): Shutting down VM
02-27 12:28:55.958: W/dalvikvm(6837): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tempcursoradapter/com.example.tempcursoradapter.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:151)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at com.example.tempcursoradapter.TodoCursorAdapter.<init>(TodoCursorAdapter.java:13)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at com.example.tempcursoradapter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-27 12:28:55.978: E/AndroidRuntime(6837):     ... 11 more
```

**Thank you for your kindness**

I have changed my table as below, yet it still crashes.

```
String query= "CREATE TABLE tbl_student ( "+
                " _id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                " ID          INT            "+
                " UNIQUE,"+
                " Name          VARCHAR( 50 ),"+
                " Family        VARCHAR( 50 ),"+
                " Age           INT,"+
                " StudentNumber VARCHAR( 11 ),"+
                " Tel           VARCHAR( 15 )"+ 
                " );";
        db.execSQL(query);
```

output LogCat

```
02-27 13:55:40.529: W/dalvikvm(9220): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tempcursoradapter/com.example.tempcursoradapter.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:122)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at com.example.tempcursoradapter.TodoCursorAdapter.<init>(TodoCursorAdapter.java:13)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at com.example.tempcursoradapter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-27 13:55:40.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9220):     ... 11 more
02-27 14:00:40.689: I/Process(9220): Sending signal. PID: 9220 SIG: 9
```

I also used this commands but my problem is the same

```
String query= "CREATE TABLE tbl_student ( "+
        " _id            INT            PRIMARY KEY"+
        " UNIQUE,"+
        " Name          VARCHAR( 50 ),"+
        " Family        VARCHAR( 50 ),"+
        " Age           INT,"+
        " StudentNumber VARCHAR( 11 ),"+
        " Tel           VARCHAR( 15 )"+ 
        " );";
db.execSQL(query);
```

Comment: Post logcat error if any.

Comment: What do you mean by "but my code doesn't work" ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari
My code crashes and display this :
"Unfortunately, TempCursorAdapter has stopped"

Comment: Please paste the logcat output with the crash .

Comment: Does the message `column '_id' does not exist` mean anything?

Comment: @jaydroider
I've added output LogCat to my question (above)

Comment: @ShadabAnsari
I've added output LogCat to my question (above)

Answer (score 3):

Just read the documentation for [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

Basically, just rename `ID` to `_id` everywhere you use it.

Comment: @NikKober You are welcome to provide your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have  a column `"_id"` in your table `tbl_student`

To use CursorAdapter, you must have "_id" column in your table.
Change -

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String query= "CREATE TABLE tbl_student ( "+
                " _id            INT            PRIMARY KEY"+
                " UNIQUE,"+
                " Name          VARCHAR( 50 ),"+
                " Family        VARCHAR( 50 ),"+
                " Age           INT,"+
                " StudentNumber VARCHAR( 11 ),"+
                " Tel           VARCHAR( 15 )"+ 
                " );";
        db.execSQL(query);

    }
```

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).

Answer (score 1):

Besides renaming of `ID` column to `_id`, you should rewrite your `DatabaseManager` methods:

```
public boolean addStudent(Student student) {    
    boolean result; 
    try {   
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();  
        contentValues.put("Name", student.Name);
        contentValues.put("Family", student.Family);    
        // etc  
        db.insert("tbl_Student", null, contentValues);  
        db.close(); 
        result = true;  
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        result = false;
    }       
    return result;  
}



public Cursor getStudent(int id) {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
    return db.query("tbl_Student", null, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
}
```

You can find the useful guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the **party**, but heres ur problem:

```
public Cursor getStudent (int id)
{

    String query ="SELECT Name,Family FROM tbl_Student";
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(query, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

**CHANGE TO:**

```
public Cursor getStudent (int id)
{

    String query ="SELECT _id, Name, Family FROM tbl_Student";
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cursor;
}
```